# SageMaker - clarification on SageMaker entities in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

## Question

Would like to clarify the entities in AWS::SageMaker.

#### SageMaker Model

When looked at the diagram in the [Deploy a Model on Amazon SageMaker Hosting Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html), the **Model** artifacts in SageMaker is the data generated by a ML algorithm docker container in the Model training phase, and stored in a S3 bucket.

[image]

However, AWS::SageMaker::Model seems to have captured a docker image to run the inference code in a SageMaker endpoint instance. There is no reference to the model data in a S3 bucket. Hence wonder why it is called AWS::SageMaker::**Model** and why not called such as AWS::SageMaker::**InferenceImage**.

1-1. What is **Model** in AWS SageMaker?

1-2. Is it a docker image (algorithm) to do the prediction/inference, not the data to run the algorithm on?

1-3. Does AWS call the runtime (docker runtime + docker image for inference) as Model?

[AWS::SageMaker::Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-model.html)

```
Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
Properties: 
  Containers: 
    - ContainerDefinition
  ExecutionRoleArn: String
  ModelName: String
  PrimaryContainer: 
    ContainerDefinition
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  VpcConfig: 
    VpcConfig
```

#### SageMaker Endpoint or SageMaker Estimator from a model data in S3

The SageMaker Estimator has an argument **output_path** as in [Python SDK Estimators](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html).

> S3 location for saving the training result (model artifacts and output files). If not specified, results are stored to a default bucket. If the bucket with the specific name does not exist, the estimator creates the bucket during the fit() method execution.

For Python ML environment, we can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to export the data and reload back into a model as in [3.4. Model persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html). We can do the same for [Spark ML](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#ml-persistence-saving-and-loading-pipelines).

2-1. What is the equivalent in SageMaker as AWS::SageMaker::Model has no argument to refer to a data in a S3 bucket?

2-2. Can SageMaker Estimator be re-created using the model data in S3 bucket?

#### SageMaker Estimator

I thought there would be a resource to define a SageMaker Estimator in CloudFormation, but looks there is none.

3-1. Please help understand if there is a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing up a few concept to begin with: an Amazon SageMaker Model is a reference to the model artifacts (i.e. trained model), the associated inference environment (i.e. Docker container) and the inference source code. An Estimator is used to train the model and outputs the Model Data (i.e. `model.tar.gz`) used by a Model. And a Model doesn't reference training code (so an Estimator cannot be constructed from a Model) and it doesn't reference any inference data either: that is passed to an Endpoint or Batch Transform.

Solving the majority of your issues: you can specify [`ModelDataUrl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sagemaker-model-containerdefinition.html#cfn-sagemaker-model-containerdefinition-modeldataurl) on a [`ContainerDefinition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sagemaker-model-containerdefinition.html) for [`AWS::SageMaker::Model`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-model.html). You would typically reference the Amazon S3 path to the `model.tar.gz` which was output from the Amazon SageMaker training job.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide you a little more context. Maybe what causes a little bit confusion was that you mixed up the [Sagemaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with the actual [Sagemaker API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpoint.html). Since the SDK implements the API calls constructs from the SDK are not reflected in the API:

1-1: A **model** in sagemaker is referencing to the model artifact and the inference image and both have to be given with the container specification of a model. See [CreateModel API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateModel.html)

```
"Containers": [ 
      { 
         ...
         "Image": "string",
         "ModelDataUrl": "string",
         "ModelPackageName": "string",
         ...
      }
   ],
```

There is also the **ModelDataUrl** is  the s3 location of you packed model artificat e.g. model.tar.gz and **Image** gives the location of your image containing the inference code. If you use the `[CreateTrainingJob][4]` everything what you store in your local `/opt/ml/output/` folder will be compressed and stored to the *S3OutputPath* you set up. Another way to specify the model artifact and image is that you register the model to the Sagemaker model registry and by creating the model you have to provide the model package arn in the field **ModelPackageName**. But than the model package contains the image and model artifact. (Note either **Image** and **ModelDataUrl** or only **ModelPackageName** can be used to create a model.
To create a Sagemaker Model with **CDK** use this class https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sagemaker.CfnModel.html.

1-2: The docker image for prediction has to implement a Rest-Service that is able to handle the requests `/ping` for liveness checks and `/invocations` which contains the payload. To setup such a service you can use e.g. FAST-API our the [Multi Model Server](https://github.com/awslabs/multi-model-server) from amazon. See [Use your own inference code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html). You may also have the training and inference code in one image. To indicate that the image is run in inference mode Sagemaker calls the python script with the argument `serve`.

2-1. Everything that is stored during the training job in the local directory `/opt/ml/output/` is compressed and stores as model artifact model.tar.gz in the s3 output path you provide. It is up to you if you store additional files there to. If the Model is deployed by an Sagemaker Endpoint. The docker image will contain a `/opt/ml/model` directory where the decompressed content of the model artifact is being copied. For the inference code you can load the model from there.

2-2. I have not seen that a Sagemaker Estimator has been recreated with an existing model artifact. What you looking for is maybe [incremental training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/incremental-training.html). But if you need to do a initialization from the scratch the best way would be to provide the existing model artifact as input to your training or use checkpoints. Both allows you to load the model during training and continue on that.

3-1. Estimator belongs to the [Sagemaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).The SDK contains classes like the Estimator that uses the [Sagemaker API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpoint.html). For example the Estimator class uses [CreateTrainingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTrainingJob.html) to setup and start a model training. Cloudformation only contains constructs from the API and not from the SDK. Unfortunatly CDK is also not complete. E.g. at the moment it does not support the CreateModelPackage API. But I guess in the future.